# Replacing one element of list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list of sequences of `x`'s and `y`'s. I want to switch the last position to the "opposite" symbol - if `x`, replace with `y`; if `y`, replace with `x`.

It is in the following format:

```
{{{x,x,x,x,x,y,y},{x,x,x,x,y,y,x},{x,x,x,y,y,x,x},{x,x,y,y,x,x,x},
  {x,y,y,x,x,x,x},{y,x,x,x,x,x,y},{y,y,x,x,x,x,x}},
 {{x,x,x,x,y,x,y},{x,x,x,y,x,y,x},{x,x,y,x,y,x,x},{x,y,x,x,x,x,y},
  {x,y,x,y,x,x,x},{y,x,x,x,x,y,x},{y,x,y,x,x,x,x}},
 {{x,x,x,y,x,x,y},{x,x,y,x,x,x,y},{x,x,y,x,x,y,x},{x,y,x,x,x,y,x},
  {x,y,x,x,y,x,x},{y,x,x,x,y,x,x},{y,x,x,y,x,x,x}}}
```

So for each monomial with length 7, I want to replace the last part with the opposite. Does anyone know an easy way to program it with *Mathematica*? I will be doing this for lists of different length: 7,11,13,15,17.

Comment: @Kuba wicked :D

Comment: @YvesKlett mine too, I've added `A` at the end to the result is clear now. Still not sure about my interpretation :)

Comment: @Kuba d´oh!  Well, go on and answer, then!

Comment: @Öskå splitting hairs ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say your matrix is `A`, this method does not depend of length of inner lists:

```
A[[All, All, -1]] = A[[All, All, -1]] /. {x -> y, y -> x};
A
```

This one doesn't even care about the depth of the array:

```
A /. a : {(x | y) ..} :> MapAt[# /. {x -> y, y -> x} &, a, {-1}]
```

Comment: Yes, that works for my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Laura I'm glad it does. It is good habit to hold on with an accept a day or two, let's do not discourage others ;) you can still upvote it if you like. Good luck.

Comment: Kuba, I changed your `;;` to `All` so that it will work in v7 too; I hope you don't mind.  (It adds a character but it seems clearer too.)  Why don't you include a pure `MapAt` solution using `All` (for v9)?

Comment: Never mind the second part; I see kguler beat you to it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wasn't aware `;;` does not work in V7. I guess I was writing `For`s back in those days :P I will use `All` from now on, at least here.

Comment: @Kuba `Span` (short form `;;`) works just fine in v7, except that a bare `;;` cannot be used for `All` -- you need e.g. `3 ;;` or `;; -2` etc.

Answer (score 4):

**MapAt**

```
dt = RandomChoice[{x, y}, {2, 3, 4}];
dt //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{x,y,y,y\} & \{y,x,y,x\} & \{x,x,x,y\} \\
>  \{y,x,x,x\} & \{y,y,x,y\} & \{x,x,y,y\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
f1 = MapAt[# /. {x -> y, y -> x} &, #, {{All, All, -1}}] &;
f1 @ dt // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{x,y,y,x\} & \{y,x,y,y\} & \{x,x,x,x\} \\
>  \{y,x,x,y\} & \{y,y,x,x\} & \{x,x,y,x\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Replace**

```
f2 = Replace[#, {a__, b : x | y} :> {a, b /. {x -> y, y -> x}}, Infinity] &;
f2 @ dt // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{x,y,y,x\} & \{y,x,y,y\} & \{x,x,x,x\} \\
>  \{y,x,x,y\} & \{y,y,x,x\} & \{x,x,y,x\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$